# Strategy for pagination with hibernate session API

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session, javafx

I am wondering what is the best strategy (performance) for pagination using hibernate session api in java.

```
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
  criteria.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
  criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);

  List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>) criteria.list();
```

But this is really slow when I am changing the pages because hibernate will do a full table scan in order to find the correct start dataset.

The application I am developing is writen in JAVAFX and I need for the pagination function the number of datasets (in order to display the correct number of pages). I did this with:

```
 return (Number) session.createCriteria("Book").setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

On several threads I read that I will have to load all datasets like this:

```
 session.createCriteria("Book").list();
```

But I do have more than 1.000.000 datasets (and the number will grow). I don't think that this is a good idea for selecting all datasets.

I thought about just selecting the ID column from all datasets and the the load the datasets when changing the page with something like "select * from book where id in (....)";
I am not sure if this is a good idea but I have no other idea.

Thanks
Hauke

Comment: *hibernate will do a full table scan*: it shouldn't. Instead, it should rely on your database (i.e. use limit for MySQL, for example). That should be fast. But using setFirstResult without specifying an order by  in your query isn't a good idea. Do you just "think" it will be a full table scan, or have you actually checked?

Comment: Yes it does a full table scan. We use informix, MySQL and Oracle. I have tested it with informix. I will try to add an order by. Maybe that will help. I will response to that als soon as possible.

Comment: By full table scan, what do you mean exactly? Do you mean that Hibernate doesn't generate a SQL query with a LIMIT clause (or equivalent for Oracle and Informix), or do you mean that it does do that, but that the database, when executing that query, does a full table scan? If the latter, then Hibernate can't do anything: you need to use an order by, and use the necessary indices to avoid the full table scan.